# Существуют ли бесплатные (не trial) библиотеки контролов для WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, библиотеки, ui

Я понимаю, что создание современных интерфейсов требуют использование хотя бы WPF, но есть же такие шутки как DevExpress. Но не слышал о более доступных продуктах.

Comment: есть неплохая библиотека "Modern UI" Metro

Comment: вам для таких вещей откроет дверь wpf. Зачем мучить то, что не задумывалось под такие цели? Вам нужен дизайн? - wpf. Нужно что-то прикладное или не столь фундаментальное? - winforms

Comment: Иногда мне просто не хватает парочки UI контролов, разве это соразмерно переходу на целый WPF?) Но я смирился с неизбежным и WPF, конечно, изучаю, но только писать на нем под свои нужды мне еще сложнее.

Comment: Переходите на WPF - для красивого UI там гораздо больше возможностей. И писать на самом деле под него проще, чем под Winforms. Если вдруг решитесь - начните читать про привязки данных и MVVM в WPF, разработка там сильно отличается от Winforms, но в итоге она проще. Если вы будете использовать подход Winforms в WPF, то кроме дополнительных мучений ничего не добьетесь, учитесь использовать WPF правильно. Привязки данных есть и в Winforms, но ставлю рубль, что вы о них не знаете или не пользуетесь.

Comment: Есть и другой вариант - новая (пока еще сырая) библиотека разработки Windows App SDK (WinUI 3). Частично разработка под нее похожа на WPF, а контролы можно посмотреть в приложении XAML Control Gallary из MS Store https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/p/xaml-controls-gallery/9msvh128x2zt. Но я все же рекомендовал бы вам начать именно с WPF и учить XAML там.